# What are the advantage of polynomial kernel methods over explicit feature construction?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

Kernel regression on data $x$ is equivalent to linear regression on transformed features $\phi(x)$ where $\phi$ is determined by the kernel $K(x_i, x_j)$. For example, when $K(x_i, x_j) = (1 + x_i^T x_j)^2$ then we are performing linear regression on polynomial features of the raw data.

My question is: why is this a good idea to use kernels compared with explicitly constructing the polynomial features? Although kernel tricks allow us to compute $\phi(x_i)^T \phi(x_j)$ without explicit constructing $\phi(x)$, in the end kernel methods still scale with the number of samples during **inference**, not to mention the memory requirement, so it seems better just to construct these features explicitly.

Comment: Although the explicit feature map $\phi$ could be intractable due to having infinite dimension, the core insight here is basically valid. The [tag:random-fourier-features] method show that a large number of *random* feature vectors can approximate kernel results & uses OLS to estimate coefficients.

Comment: A main advantage of kernel methods is that for certain kernels (said to be *nondegenerate*), the implied feature space is infinite dimensional, and so cannot be explicitly constructed on a computer. Example: $K(x1,x2)=e^{-\Vert x1-x2\Vert^2_2}$.

Comment: @JohnMadden I don't think infinite number of features is an advantage. We can always construct a finite but large number of features to make the inner product between features closer to the kernel value, and it's not like kernel methods can work on larger data than explicit feature engineering due to avoiding construction these features.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely true (indeed, it's what Sycorax is talking about). But "finite but large" may be much larger than $N$, depending on the details. And feature engineering comes with labor costs.

Comment: I agree, although I think usually the number of "relevant features" is usually relatively small. For example, the features of RBF kernel are squared exponential functions continuously located on the real axis, and we can sparsely sample these features. Explicitly constructed features also allow us to perform L1 regularization for feature selection, which is not possible for kernel methods since they only allow L2 regularization (as far as I know)

Comment: "located on *the* real axis" are you specifically interested in 1D problems? This becomes much harder in higher dimensions. But see also sparse variational GPs which do essentially this. If you have many input dimensions, you can do variable selection in the input space via L1 regularization (different from what you're suggesting), but much more popular is the Automatic Relevance Determination principle, see .e.g http://etudes.tiao.io/auto_examples/gaussian_processes/plot_gp_regression_ard.html